# WebでMP3のタグ情報を拾いたい

Tags: javascript, html

お世話になります。

Html5で簡易な音楽プレーヤー(MP3限定)を作りたいのですが、
MP3内に含まれているタグ情報(アーティスト名やタイトルなどの情報)を
表示させたいと思っています。
http://kiritter.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/04/25/210906
上記様のサイトを試してみたのですが、全然動きませんでした。

PHPを使用すればできるのは知っていますが、できるだけ軽い方法で取得したいです。
Html5のみ、あるいはjavascript(jquery)を使用してできれば望ましいのですが、
それは可能でしょうか。

サンプルなど提示していただけますと助かります。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 4):

そのサイトを試しましたがちゃんと動きましたよ。
古いブラウザを使っていると当然動きませんが。

そこに書いてあるようにバイナリを見て取ってくるのはそう難しくありません。
情報が含まれているID3タグにもいろいろバージョンがあるのでそこは厄介ですが、フォーマットについてはここを見れば分かります。
http://akabeko.me/blog/memo/mp3/

Comment: ありがとうございます。

私はChrome、もちろん最新版でやっていますが、すべて『undefined』に
なってしまいます。プロパティで見てみても、MediaPlayerで再生しても
きちんと表示されるのですが…。

Comment: ID3のバージョンが2.3でないのでは？
そのサイトは2.3のみしか対応していません。

Comment: ツールの『Mp3Tag』などを使って、いろいろなデータで確認しながらやっていますが、どうしても出ません。
もう少し調べてみますが、他に取得できる方法はありますか？

Comment: ではこのファイルで試して見てください。
http://www.1101.com/store/homemade/sample/
このファイルでダメならブラウザの問題ですし、このファイルで成功するならファイルの問題です。

Comment: 返答が遅れました。ごめんなさい。
試してみましたが、ご指摘のファイルではきちんと表示されました。
今更ながらですが、サンプルのソースは動いているようです。
でも、自分でCDなどから取り込んだファイルはうまくいきません。
エクスプローラーでの表示、Mp3Tag、プロパティからの詳細情報、
WMPで再生などで試しても正しくタグが入っているデータなのですが、
このサンプルだと表示できませんでした(undefined)。
データが原因というのは解ったのですが、そこから先をどうすればいいのかが
解りません。

Comment: ですから、タグにもバージョンがいろいろあって、そのサイトでは最もメジャーであるID3の2系のバージョン3しか対応していないのです。
ID3の2系の中ではほぼver.3が普及していますから、おそらくそれは1系でしょう。
Tag表示のツールでバージョンが確認できませんか？
1系だと画像などが含められず制作物として面白くはありませんが、対応は簡単です。
とは言え2系がバイナリの頭に付くの対して1系はお尻につくことからしてフォーマットが全然違います。
また一方2系の2.2/2.3/2.4もかなりフォーマットが違うので全対応しようとするのは大変です。
とりあえず1.1と2.3を対応しておけばいいのではないでしょうか。